# php array insert and print

Tags: php, arrays

This is a part of my PHP program.

```
//for example: $rec_count = 30

$totalpages=(int)$rec_count/10;     
$index=0;           
$pageslink[$totalpages]='';
while($index <= $totalpages ){
        $pageslink['index']=$index;
        echo '<br>Index: '.$index.'<br>';
        echo '<br>Page '.$pageslink['index'].' ';
        $index++;
    }

print_r($pageslink);
```

**It comes out like this:**

```
Index: 0

Page 0

Index: 1

Page 1

Index: 2

Page 2

Index: 3

Page 3 Array ( [3] => [index] => 3 )
```

Its supposed to be `pageslink[0] = 1; pageslink[1 ]= 2; pageslink[3] = 3;` But When I `print_r()` the `pageslink` array , only 3 as a value. I've been trying to find out why only 3 is inserted as value in array.

I am a beginner, so thank you in advance for your help. It will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're using

```
$pageslink['index'] = $index;
```

Meaning you set the item with the named key `'index'` in your array to the value of your variable `$index`, instead of using `$index` as your key.

In PHP (and many other languages) you can refer to an item in an array with its `index` number (0, 1, 2, etc.) or by a word (`named key`).
For example:

```
$myArray = ['John', 'London'];
echo $myArray[0]; // John
echo $myAray[1]; // London
```

or

```
$myArray = ['name' => 'John', 'city' => 'london'];
echo $myArray['name']; // John
echo $myArray['city']; // London
```

What you are doing now is setting the same item in your array (the item you're calling `index`) to a new value every loop, overwriting its old value. So after all the loops you'll only have the last value saved.

You want something like this:

```
$pageslink[$index] = $index + 1;
```

Which will translate to:

```
$pageslink[0] = 1; // first loop
$pageslink[1] = 2; // second loop
$pageslink[2] = 3; // third loop
```

By the way, a for loop would be cleaner in your example code:

```
$rec_count = 30
$totalpages=(int)$rec_count/10;
$pageslink = array(); // this is how to create an array, not with ''
for($i=0;i<$totalpages;$i++){
    $pageslink[] = $i;
}
print_r($pageslink);
```

Comment: If this post helped, please accept it as the answer so others can easily find it later.

Answer (score 0):

In the short version of this answer, arrays in PHP start counting from `0`, not `1`. So on the first loop it would be `0` and the second loop it would be `1` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You over complicate the code here, try:

```
$totalpages=(int)$rec_count/10;     
$index=0;           
$pageslink = array();
while($index <= $totalpages ){
        $pageslink[]=$index+1;
        echo '<br>Index: '.$index.'<br>';
        echo '<br>Page '.$pageslink[$index].' ';
        $index++;
    }

print_r($pageslink);
```

But this code is very weird. You just create array of `n` elements.

Could you explain what do you try to achieve  here?

Comment: pagination for my webpage

Comment: there is no pagination yet. that is just useless array. when you do pagination you need following info imho: `max_page_id`, `current_page_id` and then you just can calculate `previous_page_id` and `next_page_id` if you have 100 pages. you don't need array of 100 elements. you just need to know what is current page number